# SQL Query to obfuscate the data with a pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to mask the data in SQL Server.

I have a column `product_detail` with data :

Example :

```
cipla 100 for men 1X1.0ML    
prod to buy
```

I want to mask the data in this column like :  CXXXA 100 FXR MXN 1X1.0ML

My current query :

```
select product_detail, LEFT(product_detail,1)
+ REPLICATE('x',cast(LEN(SUBSTRING (product_detail,0,PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%',product_detail))) as nvarchar)-1)
+ left(SUBSTRING(product_detail, PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%',product_detail)-1,1),1)
+ REPLACE(product_detail,SUBSTRING (product_detail,0,PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%',product_detail)),'')
from Product
```

My current output is :

```
CXXXA 100 for men 1X1.0ML
 pXXd to buy
```

Expected output is :

```
 CXXA 100 fXX mXX 1X1.0ML
 pXXd tX bXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string is transformed in the format of a JSON array, then it can be unnested via OPENJSON.

The values can then be masked and stitched back up with STRING_AGG (if your MS SQL Server version supports it)

Instead of using OPENJSON the function STRING_SPLIT can be used instead.  But with OPENJSON you can order by the key.

> ```
> select id, ca.product_detail
> from Product
> cross apply (
>  select string_agg(
>    case
>    when value like '[A-Z]%' and len(value) > 2
>    then stuff(value, 2, len(value)-2, replicate('X',len(value)-2))
>    else value
>    end, ' ') 
>    within group (order by [key]) as product_detail
>  from openjson('["'+
>  replace(ltrim(rtrim(product_detail)),' ','","')+'"]') js
> ) ca
> ```

> | id | product_detail |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | cXXXa 100 fXr mXn 1X1.0ML |
> | 2 | pXXd to bXy |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c6d45f170f5eb6d3f283c8024eb59220)*